# How to remove the string from starting after certain character

Tags: php, string, escaping, character

I have a string: `/userPosts/hemlata993/20`
I want to remove this `/userPosts/hemlata993/`.

I checked some answers but not being able to remove the first part. How can I do that? I am using php.

$string = `/userPosts/hemlata993/20`

I want the output as `20` because 20 is the directory or file name that I want to get

Comment: You need to explain more. Why does the output be ``20`` in this case?

Comment: @MajedBadawi I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: You might be able to use `mod_rewrite` so that comes over as a GET parameter, presuming this is a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
$p =  basename(parse_url("/userPosts/hemlata993/20")['path']);
echo $p; //20
```

Comment: You can remove `parse_url()`.

Comment: Can I store this in a variable? As I need to store the value 20

Comment: @iachi yes it can be stored normally. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you want and the format of the string is always going to be like the one that you provided, this will work:

```
$string = "/userPosts/hemlata993/20";
$string_arr = (explode("/",$string));
echo $string_arr[3];
```